# Jquery Selector on Select with no Option

Tags: jquery, html-select, selector

I got a code:

```
$('select :not(option[value])').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

HTML:

```
<select>
<option>A</option>
<option value=''>B</option>
<option value='1'>C</option>
</select>
```

Now i want to select option A. Option with no value attribute. But my jquery code doesn't work. Any idea using selector?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You want to set the first option to selected, but isn't it always going to be selected by default since you haven't set selected explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:not()` simply takes selectors. From [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) you can see that attributes are defined within `[square brackets]` and since you want the `options` without the `value` `attr`, this should work:

```
$('option:not([value])').attr('selected', 'selected');
```